# How to Perform Search Containing Brackets {} in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to do a project wide search against the text string {{email}},  but VS code displays the error:

`invalid regular expression: /{{email}}: Loan Quantifer Bracket.`

How do I configure VS code to accept these kinds of searches ?

Comment: Just escape them:  `\{\{email\}\}` assuming you are doing a regex search.  If not, you do not have to escape them.

Comment: does VS code display which search mode it is in?  how do we tell it to perform a regular text search

Comment: If doing a Search (across files) on the far right is a button with `.*` on it.  You can click that to enable/disable - it'll look different. between the two states.  There is a similar `.*` option button at the end of the input for the Find widget.

Comment: @Mark cool thanks that seems to work